# Who is eligible to receive Sadqa Fitr?

Tags: ramadan, sadaqah-al-fitr

Sadqa fitr is something(money) that we(Muslims) offer at the end of the Ramazan. But it is entirely different from Zakat. May I know what is the amount of Sadqa Fitr that a Muslim should a pay and who is primarily eligible to receive the Sadqa Fitr.

Comment: Interesting question. I find some major sources (including Wikipedia English and Indonesian Wikipedia) say that the recipients are the same as Zakat. But some fatwa say that it's closer to charity, and can be used to help non-Muslims as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:**

> May I know what is the amount of Sadqa Fitr that a Muslim should a pay

**Answer for question 1:**

> (Abu Sa'eed al-Khudri (may Allaah be pleased with him) said):
>
> "At the time of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
> him) we used to give it in the form of a saa' of food…"
>
> (Reported by al-Bukhaari, 1412).

---

**Question 2:**

> Who is primarily eligible to recieve the Sadqa Fitr.

**Answer for question 2:**

> (Al-Shaafa'i said):
>
> "Zakaat al-fitr should be divided among those among whom zakaat
> al-maal is divided, and it should not be spent anywhere else. It
> should be shared out among the poor and needy, slaves who have made a
> contract to purchase their freedom from their masters, debtors, those
> who are fighting in the way of Allaah, and wafarers."
>
> (Kitaab al-Umm: Baab Dayah Zakaat al-Fitr qabla Qasmihaa).

Above answers extracted from full ruling which can be seen [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120409120120/http://islamqa.info/en/ref/books/54).

Answer (score 0):

Any Muslim who is not eligible to give zakaat can receive Sadaqatul Fitr, meaning: any Muslim who can receive Zakaat can be given Sadaqatul Fitr.

Comment: This answer does not meet our quality standards. Please edit your answer to include some Islamic sources that back up your answer. For more information on how to answer a question well, please see our [How to Answer Guide](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/answering)