# I have some questions about zakat-ul-Fitr

Tags: sadaqah-al-fitr

I have a father, a mother, my elder brother and, one elder sister.
I have some questions in my mind about zakat-ul-Fitr.

- Who ought to give zakat-ul-Fitr?

  Whom do we give zakat-ul-Fitr?

  How much we need to give zakat-ul-Fitr?

Comment: Do you meant Zakatul Fitr?

Comment: @seeker I am talking about Fitrah which we ought to give before Eid-ul-Fitr

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who is eligible to receive Sadqa Fitr?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2222/who-is-eligible-to-receive-sadqa-fitr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who ought to give Fitrah?

It depends on who is earning in the household. If it is your father and rest of the family is not, then he has to do that. If all of you are earning, then you all can give their own Zakat al-Fitr.

> Whom do we give Fitrah?

Many Masjids and Islamic organizations collect Zakat al-Fitr to give to the needy and poor. You can give it to them or find deserving people in your family or neighborhood if you want to do it yourself.

> How much we need to give Fitrah?

This depends on where you live as Zakat al-Fitr is associated to cost of food. The Masjids and Islamic organizations which are collecting it, can tell you the exact amount per person.

**Please note:**

- that Zakat al-Fitr has to be paid for **all** people in your household.
- it has to be paid **before** Eid prayers. It is better not to wait until the last minute, so pay it as soon as possible.

Comment: I think it is wheat. I want to know what weight should we consider so that I can calculate it's price

Comment: @MurtazaA. Probably you are correct. IIRC the weigh is 1.75kg.